# How to debug which div or component is scrolling?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

### Revamped question

I'm having trouble identifying which component is scrolling in Angular, also using Augury for debugging tool.

I have the following Component structure

```
Structure
|- main.ts
|- index.html
|- app
|-  |- app.module.ts
|-  |- app.components.ts
|-  |- app.components.html
|-  |- comp1
|-  |-  |- app.comp1.ts
|-  |-  |- app.comp1.html
|-  |-  |- comp2
|-  |-  |-  |-  
|-  |-  |-  |- app.comp2.ts
|-  |-  |-  |- app.comp2.html
```

Steps I've taken

1. Tried implementing window accessor service. Calling the  `this.window.window.scrollTo(0,0)` method didn't seem to help. And logging y position shows 0. So I assumed it's now the window that needs to be adjusted.
   window that's scrolling
2. Inside component 1 ts, i added local variable called scrollTop, then
   in component 1 html, I slowly started adding [scrollTop]="scrollTop"
   to each div. On a **reset tap button**, I'd try to invoke the
   scrollTop=0 to scroll back up. Didn't solve it
3. I then assumed maybe it's inside app or component 2. So I added an
   eventemitter inside component1, and added an event listener and now
   on the same *reset tap button** would invoke similar function in
   both components. I also repeated process over there with local
   scrollTop variable, and slowly attached to each div in both
   components.

I'm not sure where to go from here

### Previously asked

I tried implementing a service that provides accessor to Window

but no matter how far I Scroll down on page it seems like it always thinks it's at position 0.

#### This is how the css is setup

```
md-sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
}
md-sidenav {
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
}
md-sidenav mat-sidenav {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body, material-app, md-sidenav-container, .my-content {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  transform: initial !important;
}
```

#### This is how the html is setup

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav
              mode="over"
              align="end"
              opened="false">
    <md-list>
      <!-- Side Nav -->
      <div id="topNav">
        <p> Filter By </p>
        <div *ngFor="let filterType of scrollByTypes; let i = index" >
          <md-divider></md-divider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <!--Primary Content      -->
<div id="recipesContent">


    <!--The ideal all recipes one page approach-->
    <div *ngIf="main">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
          <p> {{item}} </p>
    </div>
    <app-component2 *ngIf="page"></app-component2>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

#### This is the version of relevant libraries

```
"@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
```

Comment: Include code relevant to the question. How are you accessing the DOM details? Where are you attempting to scroll to top? We need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Most likely the problem is that it isn't window that is scrolling and you're checking scrollposition on window. Check scrollposition on the div that is scrolling instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One extra debug approach involves the following:

**Right click and inspect**  the content that's scrollable. 
**Type in console** `$0.scrollTop`, if the value returned is 0, then continue propagating to the higher layer.

Eventually found out it's a div hidden inside MdSideNavbar of material 2[image]

Then in the controller side. (component.ts) I added a line for selecting cdk-scrollable, and assigned its scrollTop to 0  (on my reset to top event listener function)

```
document.querySelector('[cdk-scrollable]').scrollTop = 0;
```